# jQuery AJAX don't runs well on my PHP MVC

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have made a simple PHP MVC framework, which I use for my web application. But, when trying to AJAX request (with jQuery), it does not behave as expected. Here are the relevant fragments of code:

**View**

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<a id="btnlogin">Login</a>
```

**Jquery(placed in separated file)**

```
$("#btnlogin").click(function(){
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"user/login",
        data:{email : email, password : password},
        cache:false,
        success:function(){
            alert("suksesssssss");
        }
    });
```

**Controller Name : User**

```
public function login()
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $this->model->login($email,$password);
}
```

**Model Name : UserModel**

```
public function login($email,$password)
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("select * from tbl_user where email = :email and password = :password");
    $sth->execute(array(
        ':email' => $email,
        ':password' => Hash::create('sha256', $password, PASSWORD_HASH_KEY)
    ));
    $count = $sth->rowCount();

    if($count > 0)
    {
        $data = $sth->fetch();

        Session::init();
        Session::set('id', $data['id']);
        Session::set('fullName', $data['nama_lengkap']);


        $this->updateLastLogin($data['id']);
        $this->updateLoginCount($data['id']);

        header('location:' . URL . 'user/profile');
    }
    else
    {
        header('location:' . URL . 'home/alogin');
    }
}
```

My goal is to redirect to the profile page, when login is success. But the function :

```
header('location:' . URL . 'user/profile');
```

This doesn't run..

What is causing this behavior? Is it better, if I use jQuery to redirect to another page?

Answer (score 10):

You can't redirect someone using backend scripting when doing AJAX. You'll need to return the url you want to redirect to (or determine it via your js) within the $.ajax() success callback.

So:

```
  header('location:' . URL . 'user/profile');
}
else
{
  header('location:' . URL . 'home/alogin');
}
```

Should be:

```
  echo json_encode( array( 'redirect' => 'location:' . URL . 'user/profile' ) );
}
else
{
  echo json_encode( array( 'redirect' => 'location:' . URL . 'home/alogin' ) );
}
```

Then, you use the data parameter in the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
  //...
  success: function(data){
    if( data.redirect ){
      window.location = data.redirect;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When using ajax it is common to use a call back function. The reson you are not redirected is moast likely that the answer recived to your ajax call is never processed as a redirect.

what you should do instead of redirecting to

```
header('location:' . URL . 'user/profile');
```

return the url and redirect using the javascript callbackfunction simply put:

```
$.ajax(
{
type:"POST",
url:"user/login",
data:{email : email, password : password},
cache:false,
success:function(data)
{
  window.location = data
}
})
```

If this still fails then install firebug or chrome. Press Inspect element to bring up the web development console Press the Net or network tab. Then press the login button and se if you get a successfull http request.